# How to edit button created by this code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I edit a button that has been created by means of the code that I show below? For example, I want to change the text of the button i=4 from "test4" to "changed4". How can I do it?

```
    containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
        button.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ButtonFontStyle);
        button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setText("test"+i);
        containerLayout.addView(button);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    button.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ButtonFontStyle);
    button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    button.setId(i);
    if(i == 4){
        button.setText("changed"+i);
    }else{
        button.setText("test"+i);
    }
    containerLayout.addView(button);
}
```

Or, if you want to set it to "test4" and change it later, you can do something like this.

```
HashMap<Integer, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Integer, Button>();
containerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    button.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ButtonFontStyle);
    button.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    button.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    button.setId(i);
    button.setText("test"+i);
    containerLayout.addView(button);
    buttons.put(i, button)
}
....
buttons.get(4).setText("changed4");
```

Comment: Thanks you , i need the second.